# External Hive Table with Partition not reading the file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created the external hive table like below and tried to read the file in the location.

**sample input:**

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
ass,adda,ada,er,asa
asdasd,asd,asas,qwqw,dfdf
```

**Extended table with partition**

```
create external table tablename(field3 varchar(50), field4 varchar(50), filed5 varchar(50))
partitioned by (field1 varchar(50), field2 varchar(50))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
location '/path/to/Folder/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Only one csv file in the folder location which has 5 columns and 1k rows

**After creating the table when I tried to run `select` query, no results is showing.**

Then I tried creating the external table **without partitioning** like below and getting output when I run `select` query.

```
create external table tablename(field1 varchar(50), field2 varchar(50),field3 varchar(50), field4 varchar(50), filed5 varchar(50))
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    fields terminated by ','
    lines terminated by '\n'
    location '/path/to/Folder/'
    tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I dont know where I am doing mistake. I am pretty new to hive. So kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, when you load data from other non-hive data/table to hive, hive takes the order of the fields as it is in source data. So if hive table is partitioned only the last columns in source data can be use as partition.

In your case I am not sure why you are not getting any output, although the output would be wrong as `field1` will be `field4` and `field2` will be `field5` in your partitioned table.

The only indirect way (not good) I know is to create the non-partitioned table first as you created, then copy the data from non-partitioned table to partitioned table. If it eats lot of space (although you are going to delete the non-partitioned table later), then you need to change your source data, I guess, to get the partition fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command `Msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>`,
which will add the metadata about the hive table to the hive metastore if the metadata is not already present about the tables.